# NullPointerException with Atomikos and Spring Batch JpaPagingItemReader

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, atomikos

I use Atomikos with **spring boot, spring batch, spring data jpa, hibernate and Postgresql**. I have two datasources configured in XA Datasource with the Atomikos pool.

I encounter **two difficulties**:

**The first is that I can't disable the Atomikos pool autocommit**. I've searched everywhere and can't find an autocommit-like property that I can set to false.

The second is a bit complex. My distributed transaction manager works because I have my two databases updating.

**But when I use springbatch to read data from my second database with a JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder I have a nullPointeurException.**
Below is the configuration of my second datasource and my second entitymanager for connecting to my second database.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary")
public DataSource dataSourceSecondary(){
    return new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
}


@Bean
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerSecondaryFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerSecondaryFactory(){

    Properties properties;
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory;

    factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(this.dataSourceSecondary());

    factory.setPackagesToScan(this.deltaProperties.getRepositoryPackageScanSecondary());

    //Conf JPAVendorAdapter
    jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.parseBoolean(this.deltaProperties.getGenerateDdl()));
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(this.deltaProperties.getDatabase());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

    //Propriété de l'implémentation du Provider JPA
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", this.deltaProperties.getUseQueryCache());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", this.deltaProperties.getUseSecondLevelCache());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", this.deltaProperties.getRegionFactoryClass());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", this.deltaProperties.getGenerateStatistics());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", Integer.toString(this.deltaProperties.getBatchSize()));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", this.deltaProperties.getOrderInserts());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", this.deltaProperties.getOrderUpdates());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", this.deltaProperties.getHbm2ddlAuto());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred",
            this.deltaProperties.getIdOptimizerPooledPreferred());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", this.deltaProperties.getFormatSql());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", this.deltaProperties.getCommentsSql());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", this.deltaProperties.getDefautSchema());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", this.deltaProperties.getDialect());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit",
            this.deltaProperties.getDisablesAutoCommit());
    properties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", this.deltaProperties.getHisto());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", this.deltaProperties.getUtc());
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");

    properties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.plateform", AtomikosJtaPlatform.class.getName());


    factory.setJpaProperties(properties);

    JpaDialect dialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
    factory.setJpaDialect(dialect);

    return factory;
}

...

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<ResponseEntity> responseSendItemReader(
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['num']}") String num) {

    Map<String, Object> parameterValues;

    parameterValues = new HashMap<>();

    //parameter
    parameterValues.put("num", num);

    return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<ResponseEntity>()
            .name("responseSendItemReader")
            .entityManagerFactory(this.entityManagerSecondaryFactory)
            .queryString("SELECT r FROM ResponseEntity r "
                    + " WHERE r.num = :num "
                    + " ORDER BY r.dateEmission ASC")

            .parameterValues(parameterValues)
            .pageSize(25)
            .build();

}
```

Here is my properties file for my second base

```
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.unique-resource-name=dataSourceSecondary
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.max-pool-size=50
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.min-pool-size=10
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.max-life-time=0
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.borrow-connection-timeout=10000
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.defaultAutoCommit=false
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.xa-data-source-class-name=@deltaie.ds.driver.class.name@
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.xa-properties.url=url
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.xa-properties.user=user
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.secondary.xa-properties.password=pwd
```

Here is my transactions.properties file:

```
# Atomikos properties

com.atomikos.icatch.service=com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=./atomikos/log
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name=deltaieTransaction
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=10000
com.atomikos.icatch.oltp_retry_interval=10000
com.atomikos.icatch.checkpoint_interval=500
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=300000
com.atomikos.icatch.recovery_delay=10000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives=50
```

And here is the error I got

```
onReadError GunSendResponseStepListener java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:192)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:110)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy300.read(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, it was because the function defining my **JpaPagingItemReader** returned the **IteamReader** interface and not the **JpapagingItemReader** class.

Since this function is of Step scope, it is recommended to use the **JpaPagingItemReader** class rather than the **ItemReader** interface because of the proxy.